# Unable to add a webview to my android app

Tags: android, webview

This is my main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
    />
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/urlContainer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my java file.

```
package szdf.asdf;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private WebView webView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1>" +
                               "<h1>Heading 1</h1><p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>" +
                               "</body></html>";
        webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a webview to my app. But it compiles with the error

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/urlContainer').

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_below="@id/urlContainer" />
```

You haven't resource with this ID, just delete it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing an object with an ID that doesn't exist on the `android:layout_below` attribute. Remove the line or add a item with the ID @id/urlContainer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no resource container with this id `urlContainer`. SO remove this line:

```
  android:layout_below="@id/urlContainer" />
```